# Implementing Logical Right Shift in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm working on making a logical right shift function in C using only bitwise operators. Here's what I have:

```
int logical_right_shift(int x, int n)
{
    int size = sizeof(int); // size of int

    // arithmetic shifts to create logical shift, return 1 for true
    return (x >> n) & ~(((x >> (size << 3) - 1) << (size << 3) -1)) >> (n-1);
}
```

This actually works for all cases except if n = 0. I've been trying to figure out a way to fix it so it will work for n = 0 as well, but I'm stuck.

Comment: You're making a logical right shift operator for a signed type?

Comment: What's wrong with `if (n == 0) { return x; }` ?

Comment: Using @Mark 's suggestion, you can change it to this (no guarantees it works): `return (n == 0 ? x : (x >> n) & ~(((x >> (size << 3) - 1) << (size << 3) -1)) >> (n-1));`

Comment: @Dan: Did you want to allow casts in the answer?

Comment: It's supposed to be done without casts or conditional statements.

Comment: Is this supposed to be homework then?

Comment: @Dan Please state _up front_ in your _initial question_ that your homework is homework, and what the exact assignment is, to spare a lot of people, including yourself, a lot of wasted time.

Comment: Why such a complicated logic Dan?

Comment: [Implementing logical right shift using only "~ & ^ | + << >> =" operators and 20 operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19203143/995714), [Bit-wise operations to implement logical shift to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25964802/995714), [Perform logical shift using arithmetic shift operator in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17893901/995714)

Answer (score 37):

```
int lsr(int x, int n)
{
  return (int)((unsigned int)x >> n);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer (modulo the unnecessary and ugly cast on the result). Right-shift of a negative value has implementation-defined behavior (or is it an implementation-defined value? I forget), so any implementation of your `lsr` function in terms of using the `>>` operator on a signed value is simply non-portable.

Comment: One issue with this solution: strictly speaking, it has implementation-defined behavior in the case of `n==0`, since casting from an `int` to `unsigned` and back results in implementation defined behavior if the original value is negative. The first conversion must happen modulo `UINT_MAX+1`, but the conversion back to signed `int` might simply be a reinterpretation of the representation, in which case the value would be changed.

Comment: @R.. Hi, can you give a example, or a snippet code, that can helps me to understand what you mean ?  Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

This is what you need:

```c
int logical_right_shift(int x, int n)
{
    int size = sizeof(int) * 8; // usually sizeof(int) is 4 bytes (32 bits)
    return (x >> n) & ~(((0x1 << size) >> n) << 1);
}
```

**Explain**

`x >> n` shifts `n bits` right. However, if `x` is negative, the sign bit (left-most bit) will be copied to its right, for example:

Assume every int is **32 bits** here, let
`x　　　　 =　-2147483648　(10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000)`, then
`x　>>　1　=　-1073741824　(11000000 00000000 00000000 00000000)`
`x　>>　2　=　-536870912　 (11100000 00000000 00000000 00000000)`
and so on.

So we need to erase out those sign extra sign bits when n is negative.

Assume `n = 5` here:

`0x1 << size` moves `1` to the left-most position:

**(10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000)**

`((0x1 << size) >> n) << 1` copies 1 to its `n-1` neighbors:

**(11111000 00000000 00000000 00000000)**

`~((0x1 << size) >> n) << 1!` reverses all bits:

**(00000111 11111111 11111111 11111111)**

so we finally obtain a mask to extract what really need from `x >> n`:

```
(x >> n) & ~(((0x1 << size) >> n) << 1)
```

the `&` operation does the trick.

And the total cost of this function is `6` operations.

Comment: I think this is correct. But can you do left shift by 32 times? That will be an undefined shift?

Comment: Yes, if `int` is, for example, 4 bytes, this fails. He needs to subtract 1 from `size` so that if `int` is 4 bytes, `size`is 31.

Answer (score 7):

Just store your `int` in an `unsigned int`, and perform `>>` upon it.

(The sign is not extended or preserved if you use unsigned int)

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift

Answer (score 3):

I think problem is in your ">> (n-1)" part.  If n is 0 then left part will be shift by -1.
So,here is my solution

```
int logical_right_shift(int x, int n)
{
  int mask = ~(-1 << n) << (32 - n);
  return  ~mask & ( (x >> n) | mask); 
}
```

Comment: It's an elegant solution as it involve no conditional statements, therefore no CPU branching.  The final `| mask` operation is unnecessary, as every bit set to 1 by that OR operation will be set to 0 by the AND operation.   The mask calculation could be simplified as follows: `int mask = int.MinValue >> (n - 1);` but my simplification will produce an incorrect result if n == 0, so it depends on your use case - this simplification would not be suitable for a library.

Answer (score 2):

Derived from [php's implementation of logical right shifting](http://pageconfig.com/post/implementing-logical-right-shifting-in-php/)

```
function logical_right_shift( i , shift ) {

    if( i & 2147483648 ) {
        return ( i >> shift ) ^ ( 2147483648 >> ( shift - 1 ) );
    }

    return i >> shift;
}
```

For 32bit platforms only.

Answer (score 1):

Milnex's answer is great and has an awesome explanation, but the implementation unfortunately fails due to the shift by total size. Here is a working version:

```
int logicalShift(int x, int n) {
  int totalBitsMinusOne = (sizeof(int) * 8) - 1; // usually sizeof(int) is 4 bytes (32 bits)
  return (x >> n) & ~(((0x1 << totalBitsMinusOne) >> n) << 1);
}
```

To have 1 as the most significant bit, and all zeroes elsewhere, we need to shift `0x1` by `number of bits - 1`. I am submitting my own answer because my edit to the accepted answer was somehow rejected.

Answer (score 0):

As with @Ignacio's comment, I don't know why you would want to do this (without just doing a cast to `unsigned` like in the other answers), but what about (assuming two's complement and binary, and that signed shifts are arithmetic):

```
(x >> n) + ((1 << (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - n - 1)) << 1)
```

or:

```
(x >> n) ^ ((INT_MIN >> n) << 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int logicalShift(int x, int n) {
  int mask = x>>31<<31>>(n)<<1;
  return mask^(x>>n);
}
```

Only for 32 bits

Comment: Please add more information to explain your answer. Code-only answers are not well accepted here.

Comment: @MarkYisri Ironic since the top voted answer on this "thread" is code-only and perfectly, clearly, answers the question.

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour if `x >> 31` results in a non-zero value