# Perform logical shift using arithmetic shift operator in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bit

Right now I am reading the book *Computer Systems : Programmer Perspective.*

One problem in the book says to perform a logical right shift on a signed integer, I can't figure out how to start on this.

The following is the actual question from the book:

> Fill in code for the following C functions.
>
> - Function `srl` performs a logical right shift using an arithmetic right shift (given by value `xsra`), followed by other operations not including right shifts or division.
> - Function `sra` performs an arithmetic right shift using a logical right shift (given by value `xsrl`), followed by other operations not including right shifts or division.
>
> You may use the computation `8*sizeof(int)` to determine `w`, the number of bits in data type `int`. The shift amount `k` can range from `0` to `w − 1`.
>
> ```
> unsigned srl(unsigned x, int k) {
>     /* Perform shift arithmetically */
>     unsigned xsra = (int) x >> k;
>     .
>     .
>     .
> }
>
> int sra(int x, int k) {
>     /* Perform shift logically */
>     int xsrl = (unsigned) x >> k; 
>     .
>     .
>     .
> }
> ```

I hope you understand now the question.

Comment: You'll need to say what you've tried and what didn't work vs what you expected.  Otherwise, your question will be closed.

Comment: What is your confusion, maybe it would be better if you posted the actual question word for word from the book]

Comment: Sorry for the poor question I have just started asking questions on stack overflow.

Comment: Okay I will post the question then

Comment: Got it this is a totally different question

Comment: sorry if i confused you guys with my earlier question

Comment: stack overflow still doesn't do your homework for you.  You need to ask a specific technical question.  You still haven't asked one.  "Will you do my homework for me?" is not a valid question.  Post what you've tried, what you expect to happen, and what part of it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: @xaxxon stackoverflow will only do your hw if it will get someone a lot of rep

Comment: read [for logical & arithmetic shift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457893/java-right-shift-on-negative-number/15457908#15457908) operator in present in C but concept does.

Comment: In C unsigned right shift is always logical. So just use an unsigned type. [Implementing Logical Right Shift in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5253194/995714), [Implementing logical right shift using only "~ & ^ | + << >> =" operators and 20 operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19203143/995714), [Bit-wise operations to implement logical shift to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25964802/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't give you a complete answer as this is apparently homework, but I'll give you some hints to help you work it out for yourself:

- for a logical right shift of N bits you need to clear the top N bits of the result after arithmetic shifting
- you can clear bits in a value by applying an appropriate *mask*, typically using a bitwise AND or XOR
- to clear the top N bits of a value you need a mask with N 0s and remaining bits 1
- you can generate a suitable mask using *left shift* by `W - N` bits, where W is the number of bits in a word (which you can calculate as `W = sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT;`)

E.g. for a logical right shift by 2

```
value              = 10001010
value >>= 2        = 11100010     // arithmetic right shift

mask               = 00111111     // mask has top 2 bits set to 0

value & mask       = 00100010     // apply mask to get logical right shift
```

The trickiest part is generating the mask, but if you think about *left* shifts applied so a suitable value, perhaps followed by one further bitwise operation, you should soon see a fairly simple solution.

Comment: I will try to create this mask now

Comment: Shouldn't it be shifted by 2!!

Comment: @Catch.Me: good catch - fixed - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It took me little time to create the mask as suggested by Paul. But I created it as follows.

First I left shifted 1 as follows

```
1 << (sizeof(int)*8-k);
```

If I consider k to be 10 and INT size as 32 I will get following mask

```
   00000000010000000000000000000000 ( 1 at 23 rd position 32 - 10 = 22 )
```

Then add it with -1 (0xffffffff)

```
   00000000010000000000000000000000
 + 11111111111111111111111111111111
 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

   00000000001111111111111111111111 --> required mask with first 10 bits set to
```

Anding with the result of arithmetic shift will give logical shift result.

Following is the C code

```
unsigned srl(unsigned x, int k) {
/* Perform shift arithmetically */
        unsigned xsra = (int) x >> k;
    int mask = (1 << (sizeof(int)*8-k)) + -1;
    int result = xsra & mask;
}
```

And It works.