# Bit-wise operations to implement logical shift to the right

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, integer-arithmetic

So I am trying to solve this home assignment and I have been stuck with this one particular problem for a couple of hours and can't figure it out. I feel like I am so close! But then i change something in the code and something else isn't right..

```
/*
 * logicalShift - shift x to the right by n, using a logical shift
 *   Can assume that 0 <= n <= 31
 *   Examples: logicalShift(0x87654321,4) = 0x08765432
 *   Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
 *   Max ops: 20
 *   Rating: 3
 */
int logicalShift(int x, int n) {

    int move;
    int y;
    y = x >> n;
    y = ~y << 1;
    move = (y & (x >> n));

    return move;
}
```

What is missing here? I get `0x80000000 >> 31` as 0 but should be 1 - But other than that I don't know..

Comment: [Perform logical shift using arithmetic shift operator in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17893901/995714)

Answer (score 0):

C's `>>` operator already performs a logical right shift on an unsigned integer. Does this do what you want?

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long int logicalShift(unsigned long int x, unsigned int n) {
  return x >> n;
}

int main() {
  unsigned long int value = 0x80000000UL;
  unsigned int shift_amt = 31;
  unsigned long int result = logicalShift(value, shift_amt);
  printf("0x%lx >> %d = 0x%lx\n", value, shift_amt, result);
  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
0x80000000 >> 31 = 0x1
```

If you are not allowed to cast to an unsigned data type, then the result of right shifting a signed value in C is implementation defined, according to [this answer by Ronnie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7636/2738262) which cites K&R Second Edition. Even if [this possible homework assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19203143/2738262) were amended to allow the division operator, the alternate solution involving an elaboration on `x / (1 << n)' is also problematic because [the rounding for division involving a negative number is also implementation-defined prior to C99](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3604984/2738262). So unless you can tell us which C implementation your instructor is using and which ABI it implements, this question would appear to have no answer that is both easy and portable.

Comment: I am not allowed to change the data type :/

Comment: @drleifz: Well that's inconvenient. What else are you not allowed to do? Can you use a cast?

Comment: I am only allowed to use the bit-wise operators (! ~ & ^ | + << >>) . Not allowed to use casting, if-statements, functions or anything like that :)

Comment: You've already used assignment (`=`) which is not in your list of permitted operators. Might want to review those requirements and make sure you're on the right track.

Comment: = is not considered a bit-wise operator according to the teacher. 

But I am allowed to use those bit-wise operators above including (=) but excluding (-, &&, ||, if-statements, functions)

Comment: actually right shift is [implementation defined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544519/bitwise-shift-operators-on-signed-types) so you can't simply cast the value to unsigned and hope it'll work on all platforms

Answer (score 0):

0x80000000 >> 31 = 1 if it's a logical shift.

0x80000000 >> 31 = -1 if it's an arithmetic shift.

In C++, if the value being shifted is unsigned, it is logical shift.

In Java, `>>` is arithmetic shift. `>>>` is logical shift.

Comment: 0x80000000 should be 1 if shifted with the logical shift 31.

Comment: Yeah. sorry.. miscalculate.

Comment: right shift in C it's [implementation defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422424/can-you-control-what-a-bitwise-right-shift-will-fill-in-c), so you can't rely on unsigned types being logical shift on all platforms