# Why is my right shift operator functioning logically rather than arithmetically in c?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I’m currently playing around with bit manipulation in C, and I’m noticing that the right shift operator is not behaving as I anticipated. From what I understand, left shifts leave 0s behind as it shifts form the LSB, and right shifts leave 1s as it shifts from the MSB.

So I tried making a simple bit mask that looks like this:
`110000`

By creating an int `32>>1`.

When I type in `32>>1`, I don’t get 48 as expected, I get 16. Why?

Comment: There’s a difference between [arithmetic right-shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) and [logical right-shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift). If you want logical right-shift in C, consider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253194/implementing-logical-right-shift-in-c#5253269

Comment: Always post an [MCVE].

Comment: "... right shifts leave 1s as it shifts from the MSB" - that's just not true. For non-negative values right shift is defined as division by 2. So, 32 becomes 16, as it should.

Comment: 32 is  an `int`, perhaps 32-bit.  00000000-00000000-00000000-0010000 shift right is 00000000-00000000-00000000-00010000 or 16.  Post a [mcve] for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The arithmetic right shift only shifts in ones if the high bit is currently 1.

Consider this program:

```
main() {
  int a, b;
  a = 32;
  b = a>>1;
  printf("a is %d 0x%08x; b is %d 0x%08x\n",a,(unsigned int)a,
         b,(unsigned int)b);
  a = -10;
  b = a>>1;
  printf("a is %d 0x%08x; b is %d 0x%08x\n",a,(unsigned int)a,
         b,(unsigned int)b);
}
```

If you run this, you will see:

```
a is 32 0x00000020; b is 16 0x00000010
a is -10 0xfffffff6; b is -5 0xfffffffb
```

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour by using the wrong format specifier, `%x` requires an `unsigned int` operand

Comment: It is strictly undefined only as the code will reveal how signed integers are represented on the machine on which the code is run.  For 99% of machines around today, they will be stored as two's complement numbers.  In any case I have edited the code to cast the arguments to '%x' to "unsigned int", which avoids the warning; but has the same effect of revealing the underlying two's complement representation.

Answer (score 1):

The most significant bit (MSB) that an arithmetic right-shift replicates is the high bit in the **type** being shifted, not the high bit in the **value** being shifted.

Thus, if you have a 32-bit `int` with value 32, the most significant bit of its value (100000<sub>2</sub>) is the bit in the 2<sup>5</sup> position. But the computer works with all 32 bits (00000000000000000000000000100000<sub>2</sub>), and the most significant bit is the 0 in the 2<sup>31</sup> position.

That said, the behavior of `>>` with a negative left operand is implementation-defined. It may be arithmetic right shift, but it may be something else.