# Different bits of two given integers

Tags: c

Hey so I have been asked to get the number of different bits between two integers.
I have written the code below which seem to work but only for positive numbers.
I would love to know what am I doing wrong.

```
printf("Enter 2 numbers:\n");
        scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
        xor_num = num1 ^ num2;
        while (xor_num != 0) {
            if (xor_num & 1) {
                xor_num = xor_num >> 1;
                bits_on += 1;
            }
            else
                xor_num = xor_num >> 1;
        }
        printf("There are %d diffrent bits\n", bits_on);
```

Comment: What do you think the "bit-representation" of `-1` is?

Comment: This may be useful: [bit manipulation - Implementing Logical Right Shift in C - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253194/implementing-logical-right-shift-in-c)

Comment: what does it mean "seem to work but only for positive numbers"? What's the outcome for negative numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Shifting bits on a negative integer has implementation-defined behavior. In your case the sign bit (the most significant bit) is most likely not shifted so the variable *xor_num* never approaches zero and the loop is infinite. Instead you need to work on an unsigned integer. When you use the *scanf* function you also need to make sure that the input is valid. It is also a good idea to break out the code which calculates the number of bits into a separate function. Here is one way to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int BitCount(int x)
{
    int result = 0;
    unsigned int y = x;
    
    while (y != 0) {
        result += (y & 1);
        y >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    int n, x, y;

    printf("Enter 2 numbers:\n");
    n = scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    if (n == 2) {
        printf("There are %d diffrent bits\n", BitCount(x ^ y));
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "wrong input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When shifting negative values right, it is common for C implementations to copy the sign bit and leave it unchanged, rather than zeroing it. For example, where the four unsigned bits `1000` would be shifted to `0100` and then `0010` `0001`, and `0000`, the four bits with a leading sign bit `1000` would be shifted to `1100`, `1110`, and then `1111`. (The C standard leaves it to the implementation to define this behavior, per C 2018 6.5.7 5.) In this case, when `xor_num` is negative, `xor_num >> 1` leaves the sign bit set, so it never becomes non-negative.

The easiest way to deal with this, presuming you are using `int` types, is to use `unsigned xor_num = num1 ^ num2;`. If your C implementation uses two’s complement do, which all regular implementations today do, the conversion from signed `int` to `unsigned int` will produce the same bits in `xor_num` but the shift with `xor_num >> 1` will be a logical shift, which zeros the sign bit.